# What word describes the form of address in which someone is called "Dad" or "Mum"?

Tags: vocabulary, names, terminology

I'm writing about what people might call God when praying, things like "Lord" or "Father" etc.

With respect to using "Dad" or "Mum", would you call them names? (not exactly - not like "Brian" for instance).  Not really a title either, is it?  How about an APPELLATION, perhaps?

Comment: I don't understand what your questions is. Can you give an example?

Comment: Do you just want a word that means an informal way of addressing a parent?

Comment: Do you want to know how to classify names of family members such as; mum, dad, aunt, uncle, sister etc.?

Answer (score 3):

Regarding “would you call [*Dad* or *Mum*] a name?”, I think a term like  *[cognomen](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cognomen#Noun)* or *[sobriquet](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sobriquet#Noun)* is more appropriate than *[appellation](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/appellation#Noun)* or *name*.

• *[cognomen](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cognomen#Noun)*, “a nickname or [epithet](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/epithet#Noun) by which someone is identified; a byname; a [moniker](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/moniker#Noun) or sobriquet”
• *[sobriquet](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sobriquet#Noun)*, “A familiar name for a person (typically a shortened version of a person’s given name)”

Note, while *[epithet](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/epithet#Noun)* has a well-known sense (“An abusive or contemptuous word or phrase”) with negative connotation, that is not the sense used in the definition above of *[cognomen](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cognomen#Noun)*.  Instead, the relevant sense is “A term used to characterize a person or thing” or “A term used as a descriptive substitute for the name or title of a person” (in which sense *epithet* also can serve as an answer to the original question).

Comment: jwpat, so "cognomen" can have a negative connotation, whereas "sobriquet" cannot? I ask because Italians doean't have a word for "sobriquet", but only for "cognomen", which is "soprannome" (In English, perhaps, could be "supername")

Comment: @Carlo_R., not really (or not particularly); see edit

Comment: I'm not wanting another word for the name "Dad", I want another word for the word "name" in the 1st part of this sentence.  I'm not comfortable referring to "Dad" as a "name", nor as a "title". Perhaps there's a more suitable word I can use here, other than "name". Hope that clarifies it.

Answer (score 1):

They could be referred to as [familiars](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/familiar)

Comment: Not really, no. "Familiar" as a noun has several meanings (the most common of which is a magician's companion spirit or animal!); none of them quite fits here.  "Mum" and "Dad" are *familiar* terms of address, but they are **not** familiars.

Comment: I understood the question to be about calling someone or something Father, who is not actually that in a biological sense. Familiar does carry the meaning of a close friend, which is how certain believers characterise their relationship to a being they call God.

Comment: That... is a heck of a stretch.

Comment: Some might argue not as much of a stretch, as communicating with a sky god!